# certificate match error occurs when visual studio solution built

Tags: outlook, add-in

When i am building the solution in the visual studio, i got the following errors:

Cannot find the certificate that matches the project system thumbprint, To sign the application and deployment manifests, open the Project Designer, click the Signing page tab, select an existing certificate, and try again.

I have the certificate file.

How to resolve this?

Regards,
Brijesh

Comment: It is resolved by importing the .pfx file with pasword.

Comment: Can it also be resolved somehow if the passowrd for the .pfx file is unknown?

Comment: It can be resolved. You can create new certificate by clicking on "Create Test Certificate.." and enter any arbitrary values.